# Uninstalling nagios

Tags: mysql, nagios

I tried to remove **nagios** from my computer after the installation process got screwed up. However,the uninstallation process was not able to remove *all* of the files from the computer. I tried various methods (used even other 'direct' tools like '`dpkg` command') to remove the installation but it just wont work. Even a fresh installation does not work.

So, I referred to the following link for the removal process:

http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Utilities/Nagios-Uninstall--2F-Reinstall-script/details

However, it will also remove MySQL from the computer. **Is there any way to *completely* remove Nagios without removing mysql too?**

Comment: Did you install nagios via the local package manager? If so which operating system are you running?

Comment: Please post more information about, How did you installed. It will be helpful to others for providing clear information.

Answer (score 0):

Please comment lines

```
 #60 rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
 #80 yum remove mysql postgresql -y
 #83 rm -f /root/scripts/automysqlbackup
```

Regards,
Seroney

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
locate nagios
```

The above command will return all the directories where nagios is present. And then you can run a script or remove them manually. By default, it gets installed at,

```
/usr/local/nagios
```

Hope this helps!